# Integrate Go files in existing C project

Tags: c, go, gcc, makefile, linker

I have a large project written in C and I wrote a Go script with a function that I would like to call from the C code (**C->Go**). This same Go function also needs to call some C functions (**Go->C**).

Here is a simplified look at the project structure:

```
- src/...
- src/file_c.h
- src/file_c.c
- src/gocode/file_go.go
- src/Makefile
```

Here is what I would like to do:

- `file_c.c` needs to include `file_go.h` (C->Go).
- `file_go.go` needs to include `file_c.h` (Go->C).
- The C software has its own large Makefile and I would like to keep using that one to compile it. The final binary to run will also be from the existing C code (and will call a Go function during its execution).

### What I tried so far:

In file `file_go.go`, prior to the `import "C"` statement, I added these lines:

```
// #cgo CFLAGS: -I..
// #include "file_c.h"
```

Then I tried to compile the `file_go.go` with both commands:

```
go build -buildmode=c-shared file_go.go
go build -buildmode=c-archive file_go.go
```

However, in both cases I get error messages of the sort `undefined reference to func`, where `func` is the C function (declared in `file_c.h` and defined in `file_c.c`) called from the Go code.

If I remove the calls from Go->C in `file_go.go`, then it compiles correctly and I can include `file_go.h` in the C Makefile properly. However, I need the Go file to call that C function too.

How can I build the Go file in such a way that the C function is correctly linked?